# Adding a new variable into a data set based on the element of a list

Tags: r

I have a list variable X and I want to add a new categorical variable into the data set based on the element and length of X. For example, suppose

```
 X    
    [[1]]
    [[1]]$In
    [1] 3 4 5 6

    [[2]]
    [[2]]$In
    [1] 7 8 9

    [[3]]
    [[3]]$In
    [1] 11 12 13
library(stats)
library(graphics)
attach(cars)
cars$c<-NA
```

Now I want to make a categorical variable (c) in a way that for the data set's row numbers or subject numbers which are equal to 3,4,5, c would be 1, for the rows which are equal to 7,8,9 then c would be 2, if the data set's row number are equal to 11,12,13 then c would be 3. I was wondering how can I do that. I need a loop function since in my real data the length of X could be around 20. It means c would have 20 categories and some of the cells would be NA. I need something like

```
In  c
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   2
8   2
9   2
11  3
12  3
13  3
```

then I need to add c column into cars data set (which is available in R) and if the value of In matches to row number then we will include the value of c otherwise c would be NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame("In" = unlist(X), "c" = rep(seq_len(length(X)), sapply(X, lengths)))
```

This constructs a data.frame. The first function `unlist` turns the nested list into an automic vector. The second element, repeats the element position of the nested list by the number of elements contained in the vector within the inner list element.

```
df
  In c
1   3 1
2   4 1
3   5 1
4   7 2
5   8 2
6   9 2
7  11 3
8  12 3
9  13 3
```

**data**

```
X <- list(list("In"=3:5), list("In"=7:9), list("In"=11:13))
```